# How to extract the value of an Excel cell at a specific time?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have an Excel cell that contains a value that is dynamic and being automatically updated throughout the day (This is done using the RTD() function that gets the data from the ThinkorSwim Trading Application) . I am trying to capture the value every minute, put it in a dynamic range and have a plot of these values being dynamically updated throughout the day; like charting a stock price dynamically minute by minute)

My proposed solution is to create a column that contains all the times in the day, minute by minute as static values and another column that captures the value from the dynamic cell at each point in time. The problem I'm facing is how to evaluate a formula at specific times.

Something like:

```
time          value
10:31:00      Grab value from dynamic cell at 10:31:00
10:32:00      Grab value from dynamic cell at 10:32:00
..
```

Right now, I'm trying to learn how I can do this with Macros.

Any hint/help is appreciated.

Update: I was able to solve the problem following Mathieu's suggestion. Please see below.

Comment: More information such as how that value is being updated and what you've tried so far is crucial to us being any help. Based on what you've shared so far, I'd recommend looking at the OnChange event

Comment: Thank you. I edited the question and I'm working on the OnChange event right now.

Comment: See [Application.OnTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.ontime)

Comment: Thank you Mathieu.Your suggestion helped me solve the problem.

Comment: Is it just a timevalue or is there a date too? If this updates every minute then there has to be a few 10:31:00 values if this has been running a few days.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem, following Mathieu's suggestion and finding the video below.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=svlbqdGE4ws

Here's the gist of it: 
Use the following Macro code and replace the two placeholders with your Excel cell names. The destination cell will be updated based on the value of the dynamic cell every second. Right now the code gets into a loop, but that should be easy to solve. This code doesn't exactly do what I wanted to do, but shows how the content of one cell can be updated based on another cell's value at different points in time.

VBA code:

```
Sub timer()
Application.OnTime Now() + TimeValue("00:01:00"), "main"
End Sub

Sub main()
Range("Reference_the_Destination_Cell_Here").Value = Range("Refernce_the_Dynamic_Cell_Here").Value
timer
End Sub
```